# How to use Light Field tools of Blender?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, add-on, light

I'm studying Light Field Rending with Blender,but I don't know how to use the addon [Light Field tools](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Light_Field_Tools).
Just like this http://hci.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/HCI/Research/LightField/old_page/,but I don't know how to use it.
Could you please help me? Maybe give me a example or a tutorial.